# SQLite - if I block " from strings, can I be SQL injected?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using this code (python using sqlite3) to add data to the table:

```
''' INSERT INTO TABLE (USERNAME) VALUES ("''' + data + '''")'''
```

If I block ", then (to the best of my knowledge) it should be impossible to exit the string, subsequently making it impossible to SQL inject.

My questions are these: 
Does this stop users from being able to inject SQL?
If no, should I add more to the blacklist or create a whitelist?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you sterilize `data` before letting it hit the insert statement, making sure that single quotes do not appear anywhere, then in theory SQL injection is not possible.  Whatever `data` gets injected should just be treated a string literal, rendering any injected SQL commands ineffective.  However, there may still be ways for an attacker to work around this.

Your best best here would be to just rely on using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.  Attackers keep getting smarter, and there might still be a way to inject your current insert statement from some other means.